# sudo apt-get remove libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev by mistake

Tags: software-installation, sudo

I ran this command `sudo apt-get remove libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev` by mistake and it started removing all the apps.

It is still running as I am posting the question. How do I revert back. Please help. I am new to ubuntu 16.0.4

Edit: It removed software center, chrome, gksu, printer drivers, launchpad, gedit and so many :(

Edit2: These are the packages removed:

```
 The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
      bbswitch-dkms freepats gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad
      gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers java-common libappindicator1
      libchromaprint0 libcpufreq0 libdc1394-22 libdca0 libde265-0 libdw1 libfaad2
      libfluidsynth1 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgtkglext1 libindicator7
      libjansson4 libkate1 libmimic0 libmjpegutils-2.1-0 libmms0
      libmpeg2encpp-2.1-0 libmplex2-2.1-0 libofa0 libopenal-data libopenal1
      libopencv-calib3d2.4v5 libopencv-contrib2.4v5 libopencv-features2d2.4v5
      libopencv-flann2.4v5 libopencv-highgui2.4v5 libopencv-legacy2.4v5
      libopencv-ml2.4v5 libopencv-objdetect2.4v5 libopencv-video2.4v5
      libsnapd-glib1 libsoundtouch1 libspandsp2 libsrtp0 libssl-doc libvo-aacenc0
      libvo-amrwbenc0 libwildmidi-config libwildmidi1 libwxbase3.0-0v5
      libwxgtk3.0-0v5 libxnvctrl0 libzbar0 linux-headers-4.4.0-77
      linux-headers-4.8.0-36 linux-headers-4.8.0-49 linux-headers-4.8.0-51
      linux-image-4.4.0-77-generic linux-image-4.8.0-36-generic shim
      snapd-login-service thermald zlib1g-dev
    Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
    The following additional packages will be installed:
      libboost-log1.58.0 libboost-regex1.58.0 libboost-thread1.58.0 libclick-0.4-0
      libcontent-hub0 libgflags2v5 libgoogle-glog0v5 liblibertine1
      liblttng-ust-ctl2 liblttng-ust0 libubuntu-app-launch2
      libubuntu-download-manager-client1 libubuntu-download-manager-common1
      libudm-common1 liburcu4 qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-content1
    Suggested packages:
      content-hub
    The following packages will be REMOVED:
      aisleriot apparmor apport apport-gtk aptdaemon apturl apturl-common arandr
      avahi-daemon avahi-utils bind9-host bluez-cups brightness-controller
      ca-certificates caffeine checkbox-converged checkbox-gui command-not-found
      compiz compiz-gnome crda cups cups-core-drivers cups-daemon dh-python
      dnsutils firefox flashplugin-installer foomatic-db-compressed-ppds gconf2
      gdb gedit gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gksu gnome-menus gnome-orca gnome-software
      gnome-terminal google-chrome-stable gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gvfs-backends
      hplip hplip-data ibus ibus-table indicator-bluetooth indicator-cpufreq
      indicator-printers language-selector-common language-selector-gnome
      libbind9-140 libcurl3 libdns162 libemail-valid-perl libfreerdp-cache1.1
      libfreerdp-client1.1 libfreerdp-codec1.1 libfreerdp-common1.1.0
      libfreerdp-core1.1 libfreerdp-crypto1.1 libfreerdp-gdi1.1
      libfreerdp-locale1.1 libfreerdp-plugins-standard libfreerdp-utils1.1
      libgksu2-0 libhpmud0 libio-socket-ssl-perl libisccfg140
      liblwp-protocol-https-perl libmailtools-perl libnet-dbus-perl
      libnet-smtp-ssl-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libnss-mdns
      libpeas-1.0-0-python3loader libpython-stdlib libpython2.7
      libpython2.7-stdlib libpython3-stdlib libpython3.5 libpython3.5-minimal
      libpython3.5-stdlib libsane-hpaio libsasl2-modules libsmbclient libsnmp30
    onboard
 qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-content1 amd64 0.1+16.04.20160309-0ubuntu1 [64.7 kB]
    Fetched 1,562 kB in 1s (942 kB/s)                         
    (Reading database ... 283630 files and directories currently installed.)
    Removing aisleriot (1:3.18.2-1ubuntu1) ...
    Removing snap-confine (2.24.1) ...
    Removing ubuntu-core-launcher (2.24.1) ...
    Removing snapd (2.24.1) ...
    Warning: Stopping snapd.service, but it can still be activated by:
      snapd.socket
    Removing apparmor (2.10.95-0ubuntu2.6) ...
    Removing apport-gtk (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.5) ...
    Removing apport (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.5) ...
    Removing ubuntu-desktop (1.361) ...
    Removing language-selector-gnome (0.165.4) ...
    Removing ubuntu-software (3.20.1+git20170208.0.a34b091-0ubuntu1~xenial1) ...
    Removing gnome-software (3.20.1+git20170208.0.a34b091-0ubuntu1~xenial1) ...
    Removing nautilus-share (0.7.3-2ubuntu1) ...
    Removing apturl (0.5.2ubuntu11.1) ...
    Removing apturl-common (0.5.2ubuntu11.1) ...
    Removing arandr (0.1.9-1) ...
    Removing libnss-mdns:amd64 (0.10-7) ...
    libnss-mdns.postrm: Checking NSS setup...
    libnss-mdns.postrm: Removing mdns from NSS setup
    Removing avahi-utils (0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
    Removing avahi-daemon (0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
    Created symlink from /run/systemd/system/avahi-daemon.service to /dev/null.
    Removed symlink /run/systemd/system/avahi-daemon.service.
    Removing ubuntu-standard (1.361) ...
    Removing dnsutils (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.6) ...
    Removing bind9-host (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.6) ...
    Removing bluez-cups (5.37-0ubuntu5) ...
    Removing brightness-controller (1.2.2ubuntu5) ...
    Removing google-chrome-stable (58.0.3029.81-1) ...
    update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/firefox to provide /usr/bin/x-www-browser (x-www-browser) in auto mode
    update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/firefox to provide /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser (gnome-www-browser) in auto mode
    Removing nodejs (7.9.0-1nodesource1~xenial1) ...
    Removing caffeine (2.9.4) ...
    Removing checkbox-gui (1.2.4-0ubuntu1) ...
    Removing checkbox-converged (1.2.4-0ubuntu1) ...
    Removing command-not-found (0.3ubuntu16.04.2) ...
    Removing unity (7.4.0+16.04.20160906-0ubuntu1) ...
    Removing compiz (1:0.9.12.2+16.04.20160823-0ubuntu1) ...
    Removing compiz-gnome (1:0.9.12.2+16.04.20160823-0ubuntu1) ...
    Removing linux-generic-hwe-16.04 (4.8.0.51.22) ...
    Removing linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 (4.8.0.51.22) ...
    Removing linux-signed-generic-hwe-16.04 (4.8.0.51.22) ...
    Removing linux-signed-image-generic-hwe-16.04 (4.8.0.51.22) ...
    Removing linux-image-extra-4.8.0-51-generic (4.8.0-51.54~16.04.1) ...
    done
    Removing printer-driver-splix (2.0.0+svn315-4fakesync1) ...
    Removing printer-driver-postscript-hp (3.16.3+repack0-1) ...
    Removing hplip (3.16.3+repack0-1) ...
    Removing printer-driver-hpcups (3.16.3+repack0-1) ...
    Removing unattended-upgrades (0.90ubuntu0.3) ...
    Removing firefox (53.0+build6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
    Removing xdiagnose (3.8.4.1) ...
    Removing python3-apport (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.5) ...
    Removing software-properties-gtk (0.96.20.6) ...
    Removing python3-ewmh (0.1.5-1) ...
    Removing flashplugin-installer (25.0.0.171ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
    Removing foomatic-db-compressed-ppds (20160212-0ubuntu1) ...
    Removing gksu (2.0.2-9ubuntu1) ...
    Removing libgksu2-0 (2.0.13~pre1-6ubuntu8) ...
    Removing gconf2 (3.2.6-3ubuntu6) ...
    Removing gdb (7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.04) ...
    Removing gedit (3.18.3-0ubuntu4) ...
    update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/leafpad to provide /usr/bin/gnome-text-editor (gnome-text-editor) in auto mode
    Removing unity-control-center-signon (0.1.8+16.04.20160201-0ubuntu1) ...
    Removing ibus-table (1.9.1-3ubuntu2) ...
    Removing gnome-orca (3.18.2-1ubuntu3) ...
    Removing gnome-terminal (3.18.3-1ubuntu1) ...
    update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/lxterm to provide /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator (x-terminal-emulator) in auto mode
    Removing gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:amd64 (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2) ...
    Removing gvfs-backends (1.28.2-1ubuntu1~16.04.1) ...
    Removing hplip-data (3.16.3+repack0-1) ...
    dpkg: warning: while removing hplip-data, directory '/usr/share/hplip/fax' not empty so not removed
    dpkg: warning: while removing hplip-data, directory '/usr/share/hplip/pcard' not empty so not removed
    dpkg: warning: while removing hplip-data, directory '/usr/share/hplip/base/pexpect' not empty so not removed
    dpkg: warning: while removing hplip-data, directory '/usr/share/hplip/installer' not empty so not removed
    dpkg: warning: while removing hplip-data, directory '/usr/share/hplip/copier' not empty so not removed
    dpkg: warning: while removing hplip-data, directory '/usr/share/hplip/scan' not empty so not removed
    dpkg: warning: while removing hplip-data, directory '/usr/share/hplip/prnt' not empty so not removed
    dpkg: warning: while removing hplip-data, directory '/usr/share/hplip/ui4' not empty so not removed
    Removing indicator-cpufreq (0.2.2-0ubuntu2) ...
    Removing indicator-printers (0.1.7+15.04.20150220-0ubuntu2) ...
    Removing language-selector-common (0.165.4) ...
    Removing libbind9-140:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.6) ...
    Removing whoopsie (0.2.52.2) ...
    Removing libcurl3:amd64 (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.2) ...
    Removing libisccfg140:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.6) ...
    Removing libdns162:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.6) ...
    Removing lintian (2.5.43) ...
    Removing libemail-valid-perl (1.198-1) ...
    Removing remmina-plugin-rdp (1.1.2-3ubuntu1) ...
    Removing libfreerdp-gdi1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1) ...
    Removing libfreerdp-cache1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1) ...
    Removing libfreerdp-client1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1) ...
    Removing libfreerdp-core1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1) ...
    Removing libfreerdp-codec1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1) ...
    Removing libfreerdp-plugins-standard:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1) ...
    Removing libfreerdp-common1.1.0:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1) ...
    Removing libfreerdp-crypto1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1) ...
    Removing libfreerdp-locale1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1) ...
    Removing libfreerdp-utils1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1) ...
    Removing libsane-hpaio:amd64 (3.16.3+repack0-1) ...
    Removing libhpmud0:amd64 (3.16.3+repack0-1) ...
    Removing libmailtools-perl (2.13-1) ...
    Removing libnet-smtp-ssl-perl (1.03-1) ...
    Removing libnet-dbus-perl (1.1.0-3build1) ...
    Removing libxml-twig-perl (1:3.48-1) ...
    Removing libxml-parser-perl (2.44-1build1) ...
    Removing rhythmbox-plugins (3.3-1ubuntu7) ...
    Removing rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist (3.3-1ubuntu7) ...
    Removing rhythmbox (3.3-1ubuntu7) ...
    Removing libpeas-1.0-0-python3loader (1.16.0-1ubuntu2) ...
    Removing python-wxgtk3.0 (3.0.2.0+dfsg-1build1) ...
    Removing python-wxversion (3.0.2.0+dfsg-1build1) ...
    Removing libsmbclient:amd64 (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.6) ...
    Removing samba-libs:amd64 (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.6) ...
    Removing python-talloc (2.1.5-2) ...
    Removing python-gtk2 (2.24.0-4ubuntu1) ...
    Removing python-gobject-2 (2.28.6-12ubuntu1) ...
    Removing libpython2.7:amd64 (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1) ...
    Removing python3-uno (1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2) ...
    Removing pyotherside (1.4.0-2) ...
    Removing qml-module-io-thp-pyotherside:amd64 (1.4.0-2) ...
    Removing libpython3.5:amd64 (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1) ...
    Removing totem-plugins (3.18.1-1ubuntu4) ...
    Removing libsasl2-modules:amd64 (2.1.26.dfsg1-14build1) ...
    Removing libsnmp30:amd64 (5.7.3+dfsg-1ubuntu4) ...
    Removing remmina-plugin-vnc (1.1.2-3ubuntu1) ...
    Removing remmina (1.1.2-3ubuntu1) ...
    Removing libssh-4:amd64 (0.6.3-4.3) ...
    Removing libssl-dev:amd64 (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.6) ...
    Removing oracle-java8-set-default (8u131-1~webupd8~2) ...
    Removing oracle-java8-installer (8u131-1~webupd8~2) ...
    update-alternatives: removing manually selected alternative - switching appletviewer to auto mode
    update-alternatives: removing manually selected alternative - switching extcheck to auto mode
    update-alternatives: removing manually selected alternative - switching idlj to auto mode
    update-alternatives: removing manually selected alternative - switching jar to auto mode
    update-alternatives: removing manually selected alternative - switching jarsigner to auto mode
    update-alternatives: removing manually selected alternative - switching javac to auto mode
    update-alternatives: removing manually selected alternative - switching javadoc to auto mode
    update-alternatives: removing manually selected alternative - switching javafxpackager to auto mode
    update-alternatives: removing manually selected alternative - switching javah to auto mode
    update-alternatives: removing manually selected alternative - switching javap to auto mode
    update-alternatives: removing manually selected alternative - switching javapackager to auto mode
    update-alternatives: removing manually selected alternative - switching jcmd to auto mode
    update-alternatives: removing manually selected alternative - switching jconsole to auto mode
    update-alternatives: removing manually selected alternative - switching jdb to auto mode
    update-alternatives: removing manually selected alternative - switching jdeps to auto mode
switching jexec to auto mode
    update-alternatives: removing manually selected alternative - switching mozilla-javaplugin.so to auto mode
    Removing wget (1.17.1-1ubuntu1.2) ...
    Removing openssh-client (1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.1) ...
    Removing libwinpr-pool0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1) ...
    Removing libwinpr-rpc0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1) ...
    Removing libwinpr-sspi0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1) ...
    Removing libwinpr-utils0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1) ...
    Removing linux-generic (4.4.0.77.83) ...
    Removing linux-headers-generic (4.4.0.77.83) ...
    Removing linux-headers-4.4.0-77-generic (4.4.0-77.98) ...
    Removing linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic (4.8.0-36.36~16.04.1) ...
    Removing linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04 (4.8.0.51.22) ...
    Removing linux-headers-4.8.0-49-generic (4.8.0-49.52~16.04.1) ...
    Removing linux-headers-4.8.0-51-generic (4.8.0-51.54~16.04.1) ...
    Removing linux-tools-virtual-hwe-16.04-edge (4.10.0.20.13) ...
    Removing linux-tools-4.10.0-20-generic (4.10.0-20.22~16.04.1) ...
    Removing linux-hwe-edge-tools-4.10.0-20 (4.10.0-20.22~16.04.1) ...
    Removing linux-image-generic (4.4.0.77.83) ...
    Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-77-generic (4.4.0-77.98) ...
    exrun-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-77-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-77-generic
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-77-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-77-generic
    itError! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-77-generic cannot be found.
    Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-77-generic package,
    or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
    Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-77-generic cannot be found.
    Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-77-generic package,
    or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-77-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-77-generic
    update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-77-generic

    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.4.0-77-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-77-generic
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.4.0-77-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-77-generic
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-77-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-77-generic
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-77-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-77-generic
    Generating grub configuration file ...
    Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
    Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-51-generic
    Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-51-generic
    Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-49-generic
    Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-49-generic
    Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic
    Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-36-generic
    Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-77-generic
    Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-77-generic
    done
    Removing linux-image-extra-4.8.0-36-generic (4.8.0-36.36~16.04.1) ...
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.8.0-36-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.8.0-36-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic
    Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.8.0-36-generic cannot be found.
    Please install the linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic package,
    or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
    Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.8.0-36-generic cannot be found.
    Please install the linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic package,
    or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.8.0-36-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic
    update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-36-generic
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.8.0-36-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.8.0-36-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.8.0-36-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.8.0-36-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic
    Generating grub configuration file ...
    Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
    Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-51-generic
    Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-51-generic
    done
    Removing linux-signed-image-4.8.0-49-generic (4.8.0-49.52~16.04.1) ...
    Generating grub configuration file ...
    Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
    Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-51-generic
    Generating grub configuration file ...
    Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.

    Removing linux-tools-common (4.4.0-77.98) ...
    Removing shim-signed (1.27~16.04.1+0.9+1474479173.6c180c6-1ubuntu1) ...
    Removing mokutil (0.3.0-0ubuntu3) ...
    Removing network-manager-gnome (1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
    Removing tlp-rdw (0.8-1) ...
    Removing network-manager-pptp-gnome (1.1.93-1ubuntu1) ...
    Removing network-manager-pptp (1.1.93-1ubuntu1) ...
    Removing nvidia-prime (0.8.2) ...
    /usr/lib/nvidia-340-prime/ld.so.conf
    update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-340/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
    /usr/lib/nvidia-340-prime/alt_ld.so.conf
    update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-340/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
    Removing nvidia-settings (361.42-0ubuntu1) ...
    Removing onboard-data (1.2.0-0ubuntu5) ...
    Removing onboard (1.2.0-0ubuntu5) ...
    Removing openprinting-ppds (20160212-0ubuntu1) ...
    Removing plainbox-provider-checkbox (0.25-1) ...
    Removing plainbox-provider-resource-generic (0.23-1) ...
    Removing plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text (0.9.2-3ubuntu13.1) ...
    update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
    Removing pppoeconf (1.21ubuntu1) ...
    Removing pptp-linux (1.8.0-1) ...
    Removing pppconfig (2.3.22) ...
    Removing printer-driver-foo2zjs (20151024dfsg0-1ubuntu1) ...
    Removing printer-driver-foo2zjs-common (20151024dfsg0-1ubuntu1) ...
    Removing printer-driver-gutenprint (5.2.11-1) ...
    Removing printer-driver-ptouch (1.4-1) ...
    Removing printer-driver-pxljr (1.4+repack0-4) ...
    Removing software-properties-common (0.96.20.6) ...
    Removing python-cairo (1.8.8-2) ...
    Removing system-config-printer-gnome (1.5.7+20160212-0ubuntu2) ...
    Removing python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14) ...
    Removing sessioninstaller (0.20+bzr150-0ubuntu4.1) ...
    Removing unity-lens-photos (1.0+14.04.20140318-0ubuntu1) ...
    Removing python3-oauthlib (1.0.3-1) ...
    Removing python3-blinker (1.3.dfsg2-1build1) ...
    Removing python3-brlapi (5.3.1-2ubuntu2.1) ...
    Removing python3-bs4 (4.4.1-1) ...
    Removing python3-gi-cairo (3.20.0-0ubuntu1) ...
    Removing python3-cairo (1.10.0+dfsg-5build1) ...
    Removing python3-cryptography (1.2.3-1ubuntu0.1) ...
    Removing python3-cffi-backend (1.5.2-1ubuntu1) ...
    Removing python3-plainbox (0.25-1) ...
    Removing system-config-printer-common (1.5.7+20160212-0ubuntu2) ...
    Removing usb-creator-gtk (0.3.2) ...
    Removing usb-creator-common (0.3.2) ...
    Removing python3-checkbox-support (0.22-1) ...
    Removing python3-commandnotfound (0.3ubuntu16.04.2) ...
    Removing system-config-printer-udev (1.5.7+20160212-0ubuntu2) ...
    Removing python3-cups (1.9.73-0ubuntu2) ...
    Removing ubuntu-system-service (0.3) ...
    Removing unity-scope-openclipart (0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1) ...
    Removing python3-feedparser (5.1.3-3build1) ...
    Removing python3-gdbm:amd64 (3.5.1-1) ...
    Removing python3-pyatspi (2.18.0+dfsg-3) ...
    Removing unity-webapps-common (2.4.17+15.10.20150616-0ubuntu2) ...
    Removing python3-guacamole (0.9.2-1) ...
    Removing python3-html5lib (0.999-4) ...
    Removing python3-httplib2 (0.9.1+dfsg-1) ...
    Removing python3-idna (2.0-3) ...
    Removing python3-jinja2 (2.8-1) ...
    Removing python3-jwt (1.3.0-1) ...
    Removing python3-louis (2.6.4-2) ...
    Removing unity-scope-devhelp (0.1+14.04.20140328-0ubuntu1) ...
    Removing python3-lxml (3.5.0-1build1) ...
    Removing python3-mako (1.0.3+ds1-1ubuntu1) ...
    Removing python3-markupsafe (0.23-2build2) ...
    Removing python3-padme (1.1.1-2) ...
    Removing python3-pexpect (4.0.1-1) ...
    Removing python3-pil:amd64 (3.1.2-0ubuntu1.1) ...
    Removing python3-problem-report (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.5) ...
    Removing python3-ptyprocess (0.5-1) ...
    Removing python3-pyasn1 (0.1.9-1) ...
    Removing python3-software-properties (0.96.20.6) ...
    Removing python3-pycurl (7.43.0-1ubuntu1) ...
    Removing python3-pyparsing (2.0.3+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.1) ...
    Removing python3-renderpm:amd64 (3.3.0-1) ...
    Removing python3-reportlab (3.3.0-1) ...
    Removing python3-reportlab-accel:amd64 (3.3.0-1) ...
    Removing python3-speechd (0.8.3-1ubuntu3) ...
    Removing python3-systemd (231-2build1) ...
    Removing python3-xdg (0.25-4) ...
    Removing screen-resolution-extra (0.17.1) ...
    Removing ubuntu-drivers-common (1:0.4.17.2) ...
    Removing python3-xkit (0.5.0ubuntu2) ...
    Removing python3-xlib (0.14+20091101-5) ...
    Removing python3-xlsxwriter (0.7.3-1) ...
    Removing s-nail (14.8.6-1) ...
    Removing secureboot-db (1.1) ...
    Removing sbsigntool (0.6-0ubuntu10.1) ...
    Removing tcpdump (4.9.0-1ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
    Removing transmission-gtk (2.84-3ubuntu3) ...
    Removing ubuntu-minimal (1.361) ...
    Removing ufw (0.35-0ubuntu2) ...
    Skip stopping firewall: ufw (not enabled)
    Removing unity-scope-calculator (0.1+14.04.20140328-0ubuntu1) ...
    Removing unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks (0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1) ...
    Removing unity-scope-colourlovers (0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1) ...
    Removing unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks (0.1+13.10.20130809.1-0ubuntu1) ...
    Removing unity-scope-gdrive (0.9+16.04.20151125-0ubuntu1) ...
    Removing unity-scope-home (6.8.2+16.04.20160212.1-0ubuntu1) ...
    Removing unity-scope-manpages (3.0+14.04.20140324-0ubuntu1) ...
    Removing unity-scope-texdoc (0.1+14.04.20140328-0ubuntu1) ...
    Removing unity-scope-tomboy (0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1) ...
    Removing unity-scope-virtualbox (0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1) ...
    Removing unity-scope-yelp (0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1) ...
    Removing unity-scope-zotero (0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1) ...
    Removing aptdaemon (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14) ...
    Removing crda (3.13-1) ...
    Removing cups (2.1.3-4) ...
    Removing cups-core-drivers (2.1.3-4) ...
    Removing cups-daemon (2.1.3-4) ...
    Warning: Stopping cups.service, but it can still be activated by:
      cups.socket
    Removing python (2.7.11-1) ...
    Removing libpython-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.11-1) ...
    Removing python2.7 (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1) ...
    Removing libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1) ...
    Removing network-manager (1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
    Removing ssl-cert (1.0.37) ...
    Removing ppp (2.4.7-1+2ubuntu1) ...
    Stopping all PPP connections...done.
    Removing python3-cupshelpers (1.5.7+20160212-0ubuntu2) ...
    Removing python3-requests (2.9.1-3) ...
    Removing python3-urllib3 (1.13.1-2ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
    Removing wpasupplicant (2.4-0ubuntu6) ...
    Removing dh-python (2.20151103ubuntu1.1) ...
    Removing libwww-perl (6.15-1) ...
    Removing liblwp-protocol-https-perl (6.06-2) ...
    Removing libio-socket-ssl-perl (2.024-1) ...
    Removing libnet-ssleay-perl (1.72-1build1) ...
    Removing update-notifier (3.168.4) ...
    Removing update-notifier-common (3.168.4) ...
    Removing python3-debian (0.1.27ubuntu2) ...
    Removing python3-chardet (2.3.0-2) ...
    Removing python3-six (1.10.0-3) ...
    Removing ca-certificates (20160104ubuntu1) ...
    Removing dangling symlinks from /etc/ssl/certs... done.
    Removing unity-control-center (15.04.0+16.04.20160705-0ubuntu1) ...
    Removing indicator-bluetooth (0.0.6+16.04.20160526-0ubuntu1) ...
    Removing ibus (1.5.11-1ubuntu2) ...
    Removing gir1.2-ibus-1.0:amd64 (1.5.11-1ubuntu2) ...
    Removing gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
    Removing openssl (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.6) ...
    Removing update-manager (1:16.04.6) ...
    Removing python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14) ...
    Removing python3-aptdaemon (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14) ...
    Removing python3-defer (1.0.6-2build1) ...
    Removing update-manager-core (1:16.04.6) ...
    dpkg: warning: while removing update-manager-core, directory '/var/lib/update-manager' not empty so not removed
    Removing python3-update-manager (1:16.04.6) ...
    Removing python3-pkg-resources (20.7.0-1) ...
    Removing ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk (1:16.04.21) ...
    Removing python3-dbus (1.2.0-3) ...
    Removing ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (1:16.04.21) ...
    Removing python3-distupgrade (1:16.04.21) ...
    Removing python3-gi (3.20.0-0ubuntu1) ...
    Removing lsb-release (9.20160110ubuntu0.2) ...
    Removing python3-apt (1.1.0~beta1build1) ...
    Removing python-apt-common (1.1.0~beta1build1) ...
    Removing python3 (3.5.1-3) ...
    Removing libpython3-stdlib:amd64 (3.5.1-3) ...
    Removing python3.5 (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1) ...
    Removing libpython3.5-stdlib:amd64 (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1) ...
    Removing python3-minimal (3.5.1-3) ...
    Removing python3.5-minimal (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1) ...
    Unlinking and removing bytecode for runtime python3.5
    Removing libpython3.5-minimal:amd64 (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1) ...
    Removing libssl1.0.0:amd64 (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.6) ...
    Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
    Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
    Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...

    W: Operation was interrupted before it could finish
```

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get install` to add them back  ?

Comment: @Egrimo no. How do I add them back?

Comment: @Egrimo there are so many packages removed.

Comment: mostly these packages are connected to each other. F.e if you install gksu back, most of deleted files will be reinstalled. Do this step for another applications such as gedit etc.

Comment: You have learned a valuable lesson today: Don't blindly click past apt questions. Read them. They are important.